Why does my passive IR occupancy sensor switch react to a nearby WiFi access point?
I have a Leviton decora PR180 light switch and a WiFi access point (AP) mounted on the same wall above (~ 3 ft) and to the side (~ 1 ft) of it. The power-over-Ethernet cable feeding the AP runs along the stud, presumably parallel to the power cable going to the switch. It's been working fine for years; then, for Reasons™ I moved the WiFi AP slightly lower (~ 2.5 ft) and to the other side of the switch (rerouting the PoE cable along a different stud), and now the switch constantly (i.e. every 20 to 40 seconds) detects "movement", when there is none, and turns the lights on.
What I have tried so far, with no success:

Shield the switch from the AP blue LED, which is very dim and is on steady, not blinking.
Disable the AP LED altogether.
Tape the switch sensor with a semi-transparent adhesive tape of increasing thickness.
Adjust the switch sensitivity to the minimum.
Replace the switch with another, never used until then, unit of the same model.

The only thing that helps is powering down the AP -- then the switch behaves as expected.
Why does this passive IR sensor seem to have changed its behaviour after the change in the AP position? What other explanation could there be? Apart from moving the AP back to where it was, which I don't want, what else can I try to make the switch work correctly?

This is barely about home improvement. I don't understand most of the acronyms you have posted and believe most in the home improvement realm don't either.  Spell out what is happening and you may get worthwhile info back.

This may be better suited for computer science or network engineering stack.

@RMDman I disagree. This isn't about WiFi connectivity. It seems to be about some sort of electromagnetic spectrum interference with a light switch. And light switches are very much DIY SE.

Model # of the WiFi AP?

The AP is Ubiquiti AP Pro; I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter though

Have you tried taping over the LED of the AP? It may be emitting more than just blue light, and it may be flickering at frequencies that you just can't see. Are there any internal LED's?

I'm not seeing any uncommon acronyms here...

@MikeB the AP has a function of disabling its LED altogether, which I tried, without any effect. At this point I'm pretty sure it's radio interference.

Is the electric box that the switch is inside metal or plastic? A grounded metal box may provide better shielding.

The box is metal and appears to be grounded.

The IR sensor may be reacting to RF signals from the wifi access point. In an ideal world, this wouldn't happen, but FCC Part 15 allows for all sorts of interference if it can be remedied by moving or repositioning the offending equipment.
Buy a handful of ferrite bead noise suppressors. (You may need more than one and they are inexpensive.) The type that snaps over a wire is most convenient. Start by installing one on the cable or wires that connect to the IR sensor. If this doesn't work, it may be necessary to separate the wires and install a bead on each wire.
See Youtube for more details under search terms: ferrite bead rfi choke noise

Unfortunately, the IR sensor is integral to the light switch, so the only wires that go in are the hot and neutral from the breaker panel, and I'll probably won't be able to fit those beads inside the box along with the switch.

@mustaccio Sure you can! Find a bead whose bore is just bigger than the two conductors as they emerge from the Romex / BX / whatever, and snap one over the pair. It doesn't take a lot of room and it has a very good chance of solving your problem.

I'm sure to give it a shot, thanks. In the meantime, just powering down the 2.4 GHz radio solves the problem :-/

Have you tried a different brand/type of occupancy switch?

@Huesmann No; that would be my last resort
